# how can I show indication from where enemy is coming?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im making a car runner game (all objects are in 3d) where in cops are chasing the player
im spawning the cops from 4 different place (i.e left,right,top,bottom)

```
private int lastSpawnPos;
[SerializeField]
private Transform[] spawnPos;

void SpawnPoliceCar()
    {
        GameObject policeCar = ObjectPooling.instance.GetPooledObject("PoliceCar");
        int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, spawnPos.Length);

        while (lastSpawnPos == r)
        {
            r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, spawnPos.Length);
        }
        Vector3 policeCarPos = policeCar.transform.position;
        policeCarPos = new Vector3(spawnPos[r].position.x, 0, spawnPos[r].position.z);
        policeCar.SetActive(true);
        policeCar.GetComponent<Damage>().DefaultSetting();
        lastSpawnPos = r;
        currentPoliceCar++;
    }
```

im calling this method in update() & this script is applied to empty game object in the scene. Since this code works perfectly fine
but now i wanted to add arrow indication on the screen where the cops are spawning as well as i wanted to rotate the arrow as per the direction. im spawning 4 cops at a time.
can any 1 help me in this pls im new to this platform & stuck here from long time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're spawning cops you can store them in the `List<Transform>` cops and remove them (if it's supported to destroy or remove cops from the game). So you'll have player's position and all the cops positions.

Using this data you can find the distance from the cop to the player using [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) or [Vector2.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html)(if you want to ignore the z coordinate of player and cops). Using this methods you can loop throug cops List and find closets/farthest cop from the player (if you want to show not any cop but closest - the most recently spawned, or closest).

After you have found cop gameobject which you want the arrow to point to you can turn the arrow to this gameobject using [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) method. Call this method every  `Update()` call and your arrow's rotation will follow selected cop.

**Update**:
For the farthest cop your code can look smth like that:

```
private int lastSpawnPos;
[SerializeField]
private Transform[] spawnPos;

//Your arrow 
public GameObject Arrow;
//Player
public Transform Player;
//Storing all spawned cops
public List<Transform> Cops;

void SpawnPoliceCar()
{
    GameObject policeCar = ObjectPooling.instance.GetPooledObject("PoliceCar");
    int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, spawnPos.Length);
    //Adding cop to the list when spawned
    //TODO: do not forget to remove from the list, when cop is removed (back to the pool)
    Cops.Add(policeCar.transform);

    while (lastSpawnPos == r)
    {
        r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, spawnPos.Length);
    }
    Vector3 policeCarPos = policeCar.transform.position;
    policeCarPos = new Vector3(spawnPos[r].position.x, 0, spawnPos[r].position.z);
    policeCar.SetActive(true);
    policeCar.GetComponent<Damage>().DefaultSetting();
    lastSpawnPos = r;
    currentPoliceCar++; 
}

//Call this on update
void PointArrow()
{
    Transform farthestCop = null;
    float maxDistance = 0.0f;
    //Find the farthes cop
    foreach (var cop in Cops)
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(Player.position, cop.position);
        if (distance > maxDistance)
        {
            farthestCop = cop;
            maxDistance = distance;
        }
    }
    //If there are no cops - can't point an arrow
    if(farthestCop == null) return;
    //Point an arrow on the cop
    Arrow.transform.LookAt(farthestCop);
}
```

I can't exactly say that it is what you are looking for without knowing the full game and code. Hope this will help

Comment: I understood what all you explained but im not getting how to put this into script can you just help me to code actually im new to this platform.

Comment: @AishaD.S. added some code, Can't exactly say it'll surely help you but it can show you a direction for solution. Hope it'll help

Comment: hey thnx it is working but not like how i wanted. still thnx for the help !